# Dedicated Server with UNET

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, multiplayer, photon, unity3d-unet

I'm trying to make a multiplayer game where maximum 4 player could join into a room and shoot some enemy, with default unity network one of the player would be the host+client, but i would like to make a dedicated server and do most of the calculation on the server to prevent cheating.

I'll use UNET to write a "room master", build it as standalone, when a client request to join from server, server will run a "room master" instance with -batchmode -nographics, player will join the game and room master will do all the calculation in the game.

There are several question and answer on this topic, but I don't seems to found a answer if this is a good approach at all.

My question is :

1) Is this a good approach?

2) will it be heavy on server side to run like 100 instance like this?

3) As I know we can't have our own game logic running on Photon's dedicated server, am i right on this?

4) On Unity multiplayer service, will my "room master" considered a CCU?

Any advised will be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain number 3 a bit more ?

Comment: 4) yes, it will but you can try NAT punchthrough so you can host your server on amazon servers for example (or even your own PC)

Comment: 3) Game logic.

Photon Cloud

All custom logic takes place on the application client to allow a zero-hassle experience.

Photon Server

The server's logic can be fully customized in C#. Several pre-defined applications are available as source and provide a high performance framework for your application. Benefit from our protocols and abstraction of low level functionality and add any feature you might be missing.

Comment: Over the internet if you want to accessible your game then you have to purchase unity match making. maybe